# Python - Way to encode foreign characters in format Python can work with?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, character-encoding

I'm working with large files in French and German. Basically, writing strings of characters from one file to another, collecting data from them, and so forth. Unfortunately, I have no idea what to import in order to let Python handle these characters.

Even when collecting data from files that Python has already converted (in french you get weird things like Ã©couteur Ã§a), I get key errors when checking dicts for things that I *know* have already been placed in that dict, but only when the items have special characters in them like in the example of Ã©couteur Ã§a.

For example, when the tuple ('Ã©couteur', 'Ã§a') has been added to a dict which collects the frequency that any given pair of words occur together, you get a key error when probing that dict for the tuple ('Ã©couteur', 'Ã§a'), but not when probing the dict for other tuples that don't contain the wacky characters.

Does anyone know a quick way to get around this issue at every level?

Best,
Georgina

Comment: Could you provide an example (code snippet) what exactly doesn't work, i.e. what results you get and what results you're expecting.

Comment: @ecik Thanks. I added this to the original post: For example, when the tuple ('Ã©couteur', 'Ã§a') has been added to a dict which collects the frequency that any given pair of words occur together, you get a key error when probing that dict for the tuple ('Ã©couteur', 'Ã§a'), but not when probing the dict for other tuples that don't contain the wacky characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: Thanks for this helpful slideshow. Woops--I'm using version 2.6.5.

Comment: Then you'll need to use `.decode()`, just as the presentation says.